# Alternative way of dynamically assigning content to bootstrap grid structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap structure, which I'm adding content to from the database on page load:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="column1">     
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" id="column2">     
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" id="column3">     
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" id="column4">     
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is, can I dynamically add the content in a smooth way to this grid structure instead of hard assigning the id of what column to put it in? This is the code:

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: "script.php"
   success : function(response) {
      response = JSON.parse(response);
        column = 1;
        for (i = 0 ; i<response.length; i++) {
          $("#column"+column).append(response[i]);
            if (column == 4) {
              column =1;
            }
            else {
              column++;
            }
        }
    }  
});
```

The reason why I'm looking for another way is that I have some filters that a user can apply to the content and when content is added this way, they are locked inside their column so when filters are applied, the grid layout becomes uneven. I suppose you could remove all the content everytime a filter is applied and only the add the ones matching the filter to keep the grid layout intact. Let me know what you think.

Comment: you can use `.row > *:nth-child('+column+')`

Comment: $('.row > .col-md-3').eq(i).append(response[i])

Comment: not quite what I asked but i also formulated my question badly i think, I jsut went with a method where i put all my elements in an array. When a filter gets applied, all elements are initially removed then the filters are matched against the elements in the array and the matching ones are shown in the grid layout.